# Find the encoding of this byte string

Tags: python, byte

Okay this is probably a very vague ill-posed question.. but Im going to give it a try anyway.

I have read in the first line of a .data file by using

```
with open('raw_000.data', 'rb') as f:
    A = f.readline()
```

(using only 'r', it used an UTF-8 encoding and that failed).

This gave me the following byte-string

b'\x10\xa2\x8f\xbc-X\x98?\xfe\xd4\x17>\xdd\xda\x0e\xbf\xdc\xc5d?e\x19\x91?\xe0m\xb0<\xe7\xa8R@=\xca\xbd>\x94\x91\xb2\xbf\xba\xb3u>)\xbe\x01\xc0\x05\x1f\x83\xbf#\x04\xe2\xbf\x80\xbd;>\xe5\x0e<\xc0\x0cS0?\xbd\xcaG?\x15\x9c\x07\xc0lX\x9d?\xc5\xa3j\xc0X+D\xc0T\x91\xad?\x13\x87\xdd\xbfjCs?m\xdd\x02@\xebBi\xbf\xfc\xd8g=*NM\xbf&\x94&\xc0\x94\x91\xb2?=\xca\xbd>\xfc\xbfm\xbf\xf5\x96\x9f?\xf4\x8b\xc0\xbfAz\x12@X\xc6\xee\xbe\x84\t\xcf\xbf\x1d\xdb\x93\xbfpw\x19\xc0\xbc\xe0\x85>|\xd5\xa1?\xe5\x0e\xbc?\x80\xbd\xbb=|\xc0\xf7\xbe\\xc5\xda\xbe\xacB\xe4\xbf\x99\xbb\r@NGB\xbf\xaa\xbd~@;\xc0\xf2\xbf\x1a\xd1\xc8>\xdc\xc5\xe4\xbfe\x19\x11\xc0\x10\xa2\x8f<-X\x98\xbf\n'

Now this should contain some meaningful data. But I have no idea how to 'decode' this, as in.. what type of decoding...
All I know is that

`chardet.detect('...')`

gave

`{'confidence': 0.0, 'encoding': None}`.

And besides that, the file raw_000.data comes from an MRI machine by philips. However, I could not find any documentation in that area as well.

What other options do I have?

Comment: Chances are there is no encoding because that data isn't text. And the only (realistic) way to find out the meaning of a chunk of bytes is to read the documentation of the program/machine that created it.

Comment: Do you only have this one `.data` file or are there other files as well?

Comment: @FlyingTeller I could find more like that, since every scan can produce these files.

Comment: @Aran-Fey Yeah that was also what I was thinking, but needed some validation. Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, apparently there is something called Little Endian Ordering. Never knew anything about it, but luckily there is a wikipedia page

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

And of course, we can give this information to python as well by using the `struct' package like so:

```
import struct

with open('your_byte_file', 'rb') as f:
   A = f.readline()

res = struct.unpack('<f', A)
```

Here we have that the `<`-sign tells us that we are dealing with little Endian Ordering, 
[details](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment). And the `f` tells us that we are expecting a float, [details](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#format-characters).

Comment: How does that answer the question?

Comment: The point was that I did not know about the existence of struct.unpack and its options when I posed the question. That was the other options I could've gone to, which led me to the knowledge of Endian Ordering types and such.

Comment: @Aran-Fey If you agree with me, it would be kind of you to remove the -1 from the answer. (I assume that is your point.. if not, then please ignore this message).
If you do not agree with me, I would like to hear more about your opinion. Thank you in advance

Comment: Not sure what there is to say. I don't think the statement "the struct module has support for little-endian data" answers the question "how can I decode this byte data". It's *at best* tangentially related, and could maybe be posted as a comment.

Comment: @Aran-Fey Aha. I would like to add that I had no prior knowledge of little endian data in any way, so I did not knew that such things were an options in decoding byte data. So having knowledge of this option, it does answer my question 'What other options do I have?'.